# Is there any way I can prevent the 'object.mode_set()` operator from setting the 'CROSSHAIR' cursor?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

Have a look at this simple modal operator:

```
class CursorModal(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "mesh.cursor_modal"
    bl_label = "Cursor Modal"

    def modal(self, context, event):
        # change mouse cursor
        context.window.cursor_set("HAND")

        if event.type == "MOUSEMOVE":
            self.execute(context)

        elif event.type in {'LEFTMOUSE', 'SPACE'}:
            # reset mouse cursor
            context.window.cursor_set("CROSSHAIR")
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            # reset mouse cursor
            context.window.cursor_set("CROSSHAIR")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")

        print("executing something")

        # this is causing the cursor to blink - it switches between HAND and CROSSHAIR
        # commented out, everything works as desired
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
```

The `EDIT` mode switch at the end, causes the cursor to blink between `HAND` and `CROSSHAIR` (edit mode default).

Is there any way I can prevent the `mode_set()` from setting the `CROSSHAIR` cursor?

Settting the cursor to `HAND` after the `mode_set()` has no effect as far as I can tell.

Comment: @ray-mairlot your edited title assumes that preventing the mode_set() from setting the cursor is indeed the solution, while my original title is intentionally more vague and open to others. I've asked the question in the new title in the post itself, as thats the only idea I have about how to go about it, but I very much doubt it can actually be done. Thanks for adding the tags!

Comment: My original title also provides important context to the problem, which your title leaves out completely. The problem is only an issue with modals, which should be in the title.

Comment: Including every detail in the title doesn't always make it readable and vagueness doesn't mean more poeple will click on it. Including most of the details in the title and expanding the context in the body is a way around this, however, if you feel the title now lacks something or is misleading you can use the [edit] link below your question to amend it. If you want to restore the previous question title without undoing the rest of my changes you can click [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/107783/revisions) to view and copy the previous title and *then* click [edit].